# DB Instance hours?

Tags: database, instance

I am trying to figure out the meaning of a database instance hours. I code in PHP

```
$connection = mysql_connect("url","username","password");
$select = mysql_select("dbname", $connection);
$array = mysql_query("Select * FROM table where field=something");
// More operations with the fetched data in $ array
mysql_close($connection);
```

Now, I am, charged on DB instance hours (Different rates per hr depending upon the the size memmory occupied)

Possible interpretations :

$connection is an instance. It spans (time span) mysql_connect until mysql_close. Correct ?

$Connection & $Select and $array are instances. The instance consumption is the time taken by the mysql engine to connect, select and fetch data respectively. Mysql_close is also an instance and its time span is the time taken by the db engine to close the connection Correct ?

or both wrong ?? Answer with reasons.

Comment: Who's charging you, and why can't you ask them how they're defining "database instance-hours?"

Comment: Apparently...they define database instances as understood in common parlance.. n guess a lot if beginers would like to know what a database instance is...after reading a lot in many places...the above interpretations stood in my mind.

Answer (score 1):

Your database exists on an instance and every hour that instance is live is a billable "instance hour".

More specifically: there is a machine, or a part of a machine, or multiple machines, somewhere out in the cloud that your database lives on. For each hour that that machine, each of those machines, or your part of that machine, is/are "live", you must pay for an instance hour.

To be live simply means the machine is on and able to be connected to, regardless of whether you are actually connected to it via PHP.